# When I use multi-table greenplum bulk load in kettle, I report the following error：

Tags: etl, kettle, greenplum

When I use multi-table greenplum bulk load in kettle, I report the following error：
ERROR:  Segment reject limit reached. Aborting operation. Last error was: missing data for column "deviceid"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are data formatting errors where the data is coming from that does not match the DDL/format of the table t_e_app_monitor log.

Check the log file from gpload defaults to ~/gpAdminLogs (https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/530/utility_guide/admin_utilities/gpload.html)

Also, I am not familiar with kettle, but add a log file to your last screen under GP configuration and review that.

Finally default for gpload is to fail on the first formatting error.  But you can have it fail after N number of failed rows and log the reason into a table for ease of troubleshooting.  Check out the doc link above and the sections for ERROR_LIMIT and LOG_ERRORS